# Hover multiple different element in list, show individual image

Tags: jquery, image, onmouseover

I try to accomplish a list of elements on which you hover a different image are displayed.

Something like this

```
<ul id="test">
 <li id="sidebarList_1">Image 1</li>
 <li id="sidebarList_2">Image 2</li>
 <li id="sidebarList_3">Image 3</li>
<ul>


<div id="imgDiv_1">
    <img src="http://www.freemacware.com/wp-content/images/smultron1.png" />
</div>
<div id="imgDiv_2">
    <img src="http://www.freemacware.com/wp-content/images/smultron2.png" />
</div>
<div id="imgDiv_3">
    <img src="http://www.freemacware.com/wp-content/images/smultron3.png" />
</div>
```

My jQuery looks like this

```
$(this).mouseover(function() {
    $("#imgDiv_1").css('visibility','visible'); 
}),

$(this).mouseout(function() { 
    $("#imgDiv_1").css('visibility','hidden'); 
});
```

As seen it is static as it is now. I tried something like this to get the number of the id element in the li (ex sidebarList_**1**):

```
$(this).mouseover(function() {   
    var myString = $(this).val().split("_").pop();   
    $("#imgDiv_" + myString).css('visibility','visible'); 
}),

$(this).mouseout(function() { 
    var myString = $(this).val().split("_").pop();
    $("#imgDiv_" + myString).css('visibility','hidden'); 
});
```

​But this does'nt work. How can I accomplish what Im trying to do?

Comment: What is `this` in all of those examples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would add a `data-*` attribute to your `li` elements, whose value corresponds to the relevant `div`:

```
<ul id="test">
 <li id="sidebarList_1" data-img="imgDiv_1">Image 1</li>
 <li id="sidebarList_2" data-img="imgDiv_2">Image 2</li>
 <li id="sidebarList_3" data-img="imgDiv_3">Image 3</li>
<ul>
```

And then use the following jQuery:

```
$("#test").on("mouseover mouseout", "li", function () {
    $("#" + $(this).data("img")).toggle();
});​
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/fdcPS/).

This uses the `on` method, with a selector as the second argument, to take advantange of event delegtation (there's only one event handler instead of one for each `li` element). It assumes that the `div` elements are hidden by default, so on mouseover, the `toggle` call will make the hovered `div` visible.

**Useful references**

- [The `.on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
- [The `.toggle()` method](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)
- [The `.data()` method](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: What a neat and nice solution! Thanks, works like a charm. Very logical described!

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
$("#test li").mouseover(function() {   
    var myString = $(this).attr("id").replace("sidebarList_","");   
    $("#imgDiv_" + myString).css('visibility','visible'); 
});

$("#test li").mouseout(function() { 
    var myString = $(this).attr("id").replace("sidebarList_","");  
    $("#imgDiv_" + myString).css('visibility','hidden'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should learn how to use `$(this)` or `this`.  The way you are using it, it refers to nothing really.  When you would want to use `this` would be like this

```
$('div').click(function(){
    $(this) //<--- refers to the div that was clicked
});
```

You can use

```
$('div').hover(
    function(){ //<-- Mouse in

    }
);function(){  //<-- Mouse out

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it both better semantically, keyboard accessible, and easier on yourself by making the hover items links:

```
<ul id="test">
 <li id="sidebarList_1"><a href="#imgDiv_1">Image 1</a></li>
 <li id="sidebarList_2"><a href="#imgDiv_2">Image 2</a></li>
 <li id="sidebarList_3"><a href="#imgDiv_3">Image 3</a></li>
<ul>
```

and Jquery:

```
$('#test li a').bind('mouseenter focusin',function() {
    $($(this).attr('href')).show();
}).bind('mouseleave focusout',function() {
    $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
});
```

This means you arnt mucking about with string manipulation, and if a user has JS turned off on their browser, the relevant items are still semantically linked.